# Ubuntu VPS > PPTP error 806 and 619

Tags: vpn, pptp

I configured PPTP server on my Ubuntu VPS (located Europe). I want to access my VPS server through PPTP from our lan which is located in Qatar. In my client machine win 7, I configured PPTP client.But it shows error 806 and 619.what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu VPS supports VPN inside a container via kernel TUN/TAP module and device.
On the other hands, installing VPN software on Ubuntu virtual servers requires the TUN/TAP kernel module to be loaded on the host server, then enabled for the container that requires access.
Please run the following to make sure your container has been allocated TUN permissions appropriately:

```
# cat /dev/net/tun
```

This should be returned:

```
# cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state
```